# mat-slide-toggle displays the wrong value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2

My problem is that the mat-slide-toggle has the right value but it displays it wrong, also set value all product

For example html code:

```
   <form [formGroup]="activeHomeboxPForm">
            <mat-slide-toggle
             formControlName="active" 
             (change)="onChange($event)"
             [(ngModel)]="device"
             (click)="onActiveHomeboxP(item.homeboxpackage_id)">
            </mat-slide-toggle>
            {{device}}
          </form>
```

ts code

```
  onChange(value) {
    if (value.checked === true) {
      this.device = 1;
      console.log(1);
    } else {
      this.device = 0;
      console.log(0);
    }
  }
```

Can you suggest me what is the problem in this code?
Show in: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zafcmh-rvgjhs?file=app%2Fslide-toggle-configurable-example.html

Thnx

Comment: can you create a stackblitz to reproduce?

Comment: Dont understand why you use (change) and [(ngModel)] you dont need them.

Comment: Can you suggest any idea?

Comment: @Aravind look, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zafcmh-rvgjhs?file=app%2Fslide-toggle-configurable-example.html

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation you should use `[checked]="checked"` instead of click/change.

please refer here. you can also check example in example Tab.

https://material.angular.io/components/slide-toggle/examples

Comment: Yes, this example I look, but in my code the different are, I use formContorlName, and I want to post in API value 1 or 0, no boolean

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zafcmh-rvgjhs?file=app%2Fslide-toggle-configurable-example.html Look